# Instance variables in Python not as I assumed

Tags: python, arrays, append, instance, instantiation

I have an issue in Python I couldn't believe to find out. See the following code:

```
class Container(object):
    array = []

    def __init__(self):
        print self.array

for i in range(0, 5):
    container = Container()
    container.array.append('Test')
print 'Last Container:', container.array
```

The output is:

```
[]
['Test']
['Test', 'Test']
['Test', 'Test', 'Test']
['Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test']
Last Container: ['Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test']
```

I thought the `Container` class is initialized with the values at the top on instantiation. Why is this not the case?

Thank you!

Comment: Oh, the joy of a mutable class variable..

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: @DanielRoseman: this isn't about default arguments, but about class attributes.

Comment: Argh, sorry, put the wrong one. Still a duplicate though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static class variables in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any attributes that you place directly inside of the class definition are class attributes, so `Container.array` is shared among all instances of `Container`.

If you want an instance attribute instead, set `self.array = []` inside of `__init__()`:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []
        print self.array
```

Answer (score 6):

Code inside of the `class:` is executed when the class is created, not when instances of the class are created. Here's an example that shows this more clearly:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     print "Test"
...     def __init__(self):
...         print "init"
...
Test
>>> t = Test()
init
```

Notice that "Test" was printed when the class was created, not when I created a Test object.

As other answers have noted, if you want an attribute to be local to a particular instance of a class (rather than to all instances of a class), then the code must be placed inside the `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.array = []
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be instantiating the list in __init__ like so:

```
class Container(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []
        print self.array
```

Class variables defined at the top level of the class are created at runtime, so if they're mutable -- like a list or a dictionary -- you're going to have this problem when you change them. Attributes set in init are created when the  class is instantiated, meaning you get a new list for each object.

Comment: But I say `self.`. I thought you have to mention the class name or `self.__class__.` or `cls` in class methods to access class attributes. Why is `self.` working?

Comment: @rynd: `self.` can be used to access class attributes as well; in fact, that's how you get to a method.

Comment: More precisely, attribute lookup proceeds to the class (and its ancestors) if an attribute is not found on an instance.